# Extending ADT Eclipse Plugin (Android Development Tools)

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I'd like to develop an extending plugin for the ADT-Plugin for Eclipse. Are there any informations about the available extension points? Or is there a general way how i can get information about available extension points of a particular plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't verified this with adt, but in general you can find extension point information from the "Extensions" tab of MANIFEST.MF (in your plugin).  If your plugin has a dependency on the adt plugin it should filter the list down for you.

Also the extension points would typically be defined in schema/*.exsd

Assumptions: you have the Eclipse for RCP version http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliossr2